# How to add automatic ID number, necessity on my queue system without any input by user?

Tags: java, input, queue, user-input, auto

So this few sample code is my queue program with manual input.
How to add automatically queue without input by user?

```
       public void input() 
        {
         System.out.print("Input ID Number      : ");
         id = in.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Input Your Name      : ");
          name = str.nextLine();
           System.out.print("Input Your Necessity : ");
           necessity = str.nextLine();
           next = null;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Giovany, do you want to generate random values instead? Or queue the elements once the user entered them? The description is not very clear on what your plorblem is

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to skip the input scanner for some points such as input id number, and necessity right? in Java, there are many ways to generate random or formatted number, i suggest using UUID for ID number as it is unique, you may check it by googling UUID collision.

Remark: it is a string. Sample code is as follow:

```
UUID idNumber = UUID.randomUUID();
idNumber = token.toString();
```

If you would like to generate random numbers only, i suggest using datetime as follow:

```
int unique_id= (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```